# When is a subgroup $A$ normal if $|G|=72$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with order 72 and $A\triangleleft G$ with $|A|=8$. Now I should show whether there exists a subgroup $B$ of $G$ with order 24 and whether $B$ is normal in $G$.

**My solution:** Firstly, $|G|=72 = 8\cdot 9=2^3\cdot 3^2$. By Langrange's theorem, there exists subgroups those orders divide the order of $|G|$. So, the order of a subgroup can be $2,4,8,3,6,12,24,9, 18$ or $36$. After that, there exists a subgroup $A\leq G$ with $|A|=24$. 
How can I explain whether $A$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: That is not what Lagrange's theorems says. Anyway, what you should almost always do when given a normal subgroup is consider the quotient by this subgroup.

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a general idea: You can look at $G/A$. We have $|G/A| = 9$. One can show that if a group $H$ is of order $|H| = p^2$ (p prime) then there exists a subgroup of order $p$.
Therefore $G/A$ has a subgroup $\hat{B}$ of order 3, and it must be normal (Why?).

Since $1 \leq \hat{B} \triangleleft G/A$ , from correspondence theorem we get: $N \leq B \triangleleft G$ for some $B\leq G$